# Python - Return third column value if two condition is matched pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas DF like this:

[image: Data]

Now I need to get UTB1050_1PCS if the condition match Brother and _1PCS and UTB1050_2PCS if my condition if Brother and _2PCS.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the data frame

```
import pandas as pd

list1=['_1PCS','_2PCS']
list2=['UTB1050_1PCS','UTB1050_2PCS']
list3=['Brother','Brother']

df=pd.DataFrame({'Variation':list1,
                 'Internal Code-Variation':list2,
                 'Brand':list3})

print(df)
```

Original Data

```
  Variation Internal Code-Variation    Brand
0     _1PCS            UTB1050_1PCS  Brother
1     _2PCS            UTB1050_2PCS  Brother
```

Filtered Data using Pandas [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
import pandas as pd

list1=['_1PCS','_2PCS']
list2=['UTB1050_1PCS','UTB1050_2PCS']
list3=['Brother','Brother']

df=pd.DataFrame({'Variation':list1,
                 'Internal Code-Variation':list2,
                 'Brand':list3})

filtered = df.loc[(df['Brand']=='Brother') & (df['Variation']=='_2PCS')]
```

Output

```
 Variation Internal Code-Variation    Brand
1     _2PCS            UTB1050_2PCS  Brother
```

There are many ways to approach this problem, I also recommend looking into [Indexing and Selecting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)